# Serilog: saving event properties added with ForContext into flat files

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I am new to Serilog and would like to clarify saving of custom event properties added with `ForContext` along with flat files

`ForContext` adds properties to events, so events can be filtered for writing into different sinks (files), and this works great.

Is there way to write all custom properties of event into `RollingFile` without modification of `outputTemplate`?

Potentially we can have a number of different properties and do not want to edit string template each time when add/remove some property.

Answer (score 1):

This is an omission Serilog's output formatting currently. Your input on the proposal at: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/825 would be welcome and appreciated.